# Can we pass dynamic schema details in GraphQL query which can be used by JoinMonster?

Tags: graphql

I'm not sure if passing the schema name as an argument in the GraphQL query will work for JoinMonster or not. Following is the query example:

```
{
  configuration_queries(table: 'xyz', where: 'some condition') {
     data {
        col1
        col2
     }
  }
}
```

so here it is expected to create a dynamic query on "xyz" table using JoinMonster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to pass schema details dynamically to GraphQL queries. There are a few different ways to do this, but one approach would be to use the `graphql-tools` package:

1. Install the `graphql-tools` package:

```
npm install --save graphql-tools
```

2. Write your GraphQL query, using the `graphql-tools` syntax for dynamic schema details:

```js
const query = `
  query($schema: String!) {
    joinMonster(sql: $schema)
  }
`;
```

3. Call the `graphql` function, passing in your query and dynamic schema details:

```js
const schemaDetails = `
  SELECT * FROM users
  JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id
`;

graphql(query, { schema: schemaDetails })
  .then((result) => {
    // handle results...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle errors...
  });
```